# Navigation bar not showing to the top edge in iOS11 iPhoneX simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios11

I'm having this problem with i couldn't find an answer for it in the past couple of days.

The navigation bar is not showing to the top edge of the iPhone X in iOS 11 simulator, Is that a simulator bug or i'm doing something wrong ?

Height 88

[image: Screen Shot1]

Height 145

[image: Screen Shot2]

No background image

[image: Screen Shot3]

And this is my code in appdelegate

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UIImage *navImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone-Navigationbar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange behavior, a couple of ideas:

- Have you tried removing the background image?
- What size background image has? On iPhone X navigation bar is higher (145pt).

Comment: Did try removing all backgrounds and still the same problem, The height for the navigation bar image is 88px, 264@3x , and the background image for the view in 812px

Comment: On iPhone X the navigation bar is 145pt.

Comment: @IQaid post a screenshot with setBackgroundImage commented. I expect to see a system grey navigation bar. If not you are still editing it in some other place.

Comment: I edited my question with more screen shots @Shebuka

Comment: @IQaid This means that you have a misplaced window or root view. Check your constraints.

Comment: Thank you it worked, `UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];` , changed the 20 to 0 and fixed the problem. Thank you again :)